# How does Enumerable.Select work with lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

I am trying to understand how enumerables work in C# (and also how they work with lambdas) and have the following code that I was playing with.

```
bool[] boolArray = new bool[100];
boolArray = boolArray.Select(x => x != null).ToArray();
```

I understand `Enumerables.Select` will return an `IEnumerable<bool>` but how does the lambda expression, under the hood, act upon each element in the array? From my understanding the `x` on the left is the parameter which "goes to" the expression to the right of the `=>` operator but it still doesn't feel like it should be enumerating.

Comment: It is enumerating due to the `ToArray`. Why do you expect it _not_ to enumerate?

Comment: `ToArray` forces the `Select` iterator to invoke the `Func<TSource, TResult>` selector on each `Current` element of the enumeration. However, i am sure that is not a pleasing response. Which takes us down a rabbit hole of questioning about what you understand in regards to the terminologies you used like *lamdas*, and what iterator methods, delegates, and possibly other things like generics do under the hood

Comment: on a sidenote: bools are valuetypes with a value ether 'true' or 'false'. They can never be null so your linq-expression will always return the complete original array.

Comment: Thank you guys, and yes @Johan Donne that was my intention. Was trying to make an array of 100 true boolean. @TheGeneral that's actually not as displeasing of an answer. So the ```ToArray``` is what forces the lambda to act? And the ```Func<TSource, TResult>``` exists somewhere in an ```IEnumerable```? Would the lambda have acted upon all elements had I not done ```ToArray```?